# MySQL (not mysqli) Insert Last ID not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I know there a many similar questions out there, but I have searched many times to be sure not to waste anyone's time, but I have been unable to find a solution. I'm hoping somebody may be able to spot something I am missing.

Our site is currently using MySQL (not MySQLi...I know it should be updated, but for now at least, this is what I have to work with).

I am updating two DB tables through a form that has been created. The first table, called 'customers', has some profile information and includes an auto_incremented customer id, and is updated by some of the information in my form. In the second table, 'customer_addresses', the rest of the information is updated towards, and one of the columns in the new table is called customer and has been indexed in the DB to link with the id column in 'customers' table. When I am submitting this form, I would like the 'customers_addresses' table to be updated with the new customer, but it is not showing upon submitting. Here is my code...(QUESTIONABLE PART IS THE mysql_insert_id() near the bottom)....

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    //Get variables from post array
    $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $address2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address2']);
    $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
    $state = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
    $zipcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zipcode']);

    //Create customer query
    $query="INSERT INTO customers (first_name,last_name,email,password)
        VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password')";
    //Run query
    mysql_query($query);

    //Create address query
    $query="INSERT INTO customer_addresses (customer,address,address2,city,state,zipcode)
        VALUES(mysql_insert_id(),'$address','$address2','$city','$state','$zipcode')";
    //Run query
    mysql_query($query);

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

I know I am connected to the DB correctly as the 'customers' table is updated correctly each time I submit my form AND I know the 'customer_addresses' table is connected correctly, because if I manually change in the PHP the "mysql_insert_id()", to be what the correct customer id is (say 35), then it works correctly, but somehow I need it to get this information from the first query to the customers table.

Thanks for any assistance.

## EDIT

I have also attempted to use the "LAST_INSERT_ID()" but to no avail as well.

Comment: Try taking the `mysql_insert_id` out of the string. After the first mysql_query, assign it, so `$customerId = mysql_insert_id();`, then dump it out andsee if it's getting populated properly.

Comment: You can't just have a function `mysql_insert_id()` in the middle of a string and expect it to place its output there ... it doesn't work that way.  Move it outiside of your string and assign a variable to it.

Comment: I know that with $mysqli->insert_id, you can place the code just as I have it, so that is why I have tried this. But as I am writing this, I can see that it might have something do with the '$' symbol creating the variable...

Comment: `$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));` is redundant. A simple `$password = md5($_POST['password']);` will suffice.

Comment: echo your $query to see what happen.

Comment: MD5 for passwords and using `mysql_query`? You're living on borrowed time here if you haven't been hacked wide open already. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords with something as flimsy as MD5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_insert_id()` is a PHP function, not a MySQL function, and function calls aren't expanded inside strings.. The MySQL function is called `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, so it should be:

```
$query="INSERT INTO customer_addresses (customer,address,address2,city,state,zipcode)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$address','$address2','$city','$state','$zipcode')";
```

Or you can call the PHP function and insert the result into the string.

```
$customer_id = mysql_insert_id();
$query="INSERT INTO customer_addresses (customer,address,address2,city,state,zipcode)
    VALUES($customer_id,'$address','$address2','$city','$state','$zipcode')";
```

Comment: Hi Barmar...I had tried using LAST_INSERT_ID(), as pointed out by my Edit in my post......but that in fact has worked, so it must have been a typo when I tried this. Thanks for your suggestion and help! I will accept your answer in 5 minutes, SO has told me that is how long I have to wait

Answer (score 1):

If you had any kind of error handling at all, instead of just assuming success, you'd have been told about your syntax error:

```
$query="INSERT INTO customer_addresses (customer,address,address2,city,state,zipcode)
    VALUES(mysql_insert_id(),'$address','$address2','$city','$state','$zipcode')";
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's not a PHP function call. It's part of the query string and is a mysql function call. Mysql function calls are not prefixed with `mysql_`.

Never **EVER** assume success with a DB call. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Hi Marc...I agree that I should have used an "or die"...statement, it was a naive move. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
function executeSingleResult($query)
{
$result= mysql_query($query); //ESEGUO LA QUERY
return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

$r= executeSingleResult($query); //write your query to retrieve your last ID
$ID=$r["ID"];
 $query="INSERT INTO customer_addresses (customer,address,address2,city,state,zipcode)
        VALUES($ID,'$address','$address2','$city','$state','$zipcode')";
```

try to get your ID with a simple query, save the value in a variabe and then do your insert